# String convert array and remove from string

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string

I have below string.

```
18,21,24,27,30,33,36,39,42,45,48,51,54,57,60,63,66,69,72,75,78,81,84,87,90,93,96,99,102,105,108,111,114,117,120,123,126,129,132,135,138,141,144,147
```

I want to fetch every 5 number and remove from the string means 
if start from 18 to 30 then  18 to 30 will remove from this string now string like

```
33,36,39,42,45,48,51,54,57,60,63,66,69,72,75,78,81,84,87,90,93,96,99,102,105,108,111,114,117,120,123,126,129,132,135,138,141,144,147
```

-

```
var allval = jQuery('.implodearrayhide').val();
       var str_split = allval.split(",");
```

I am trying this code but didn't userstand how i remove 5 number when loop complete after 5

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean by loop? Where are you looping? If you want to split this into an array of arrays, all of 5 or fewer elements then you can do this `var groups = []; while (nums.length > 0) { groups.push(nums.splice(0,5)); }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're looking for [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
> str = "18,21,24,27,30,33,36,39,42,45,48,51,54,57,60,63,66,69,72,75,78,81,84,87,90,93,96,99,102,105,108,111,114,117,120,123,126,129,132,135,138,141,144,147"
> newstr = str.split(",").slice(5).join()
"33,36,39,42,45,48,51,54,57,60,63,66,69,72,75,78,81,84,87,90,93,96,99,102,105,108,111,114,117,120,123,126,129,132,135,138,141,144,147"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.filter` like so:

```
var split = allval.split(",").filter(function(i) {
    return i % 5 === 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `array.slice(i, i+4)` like in http://jsfiddle.net/k2kST/

I am guessing that you want to remove every 5th element of the array...

Answer (score 0):

### JS code

```
var str = "18,21,24,27,30,33,36,39,42,45,48,51,54,57,60,63,66,69,72,75,78,81,84,87,90,93,96,99,102,105,108,111,114,117,120,123,126,129,132,135,138,141,144,147";
while (str.length > 0) {
    str = str.replace(str.split(",", 5).join(), "").replace(/^,/, "");
    console.log(str);
}
```

### O/P

```
33,36,39,42,45,48,51,54,57,60,63,66,69,72,75,78,81,84,87,90,93,96,99,102,105,108,111,114,117,120,123,126,129,132,135,138,141,144,147
48,51,54,57,60,63,66,69,72,75,78,81,84,87,90,93,96,99,102,105,108,111,114,117,120,123,126,129,132,135,138,141,144,147
63,66,69,72,75,78,81,84,87,90,93,96,99,102,105,108,111,114,117,120,123,126,129,132,135,138,141,144,147
78,81,84,87,90,93,96,99,102,105,108,111,114,117,120,123,126,129,132,135,138,141,144,147
93,96,99,102,105,108,111,114,117,120,123,126,129,132,135,138,141,144,147
108,111,114,117,120,123,126,129,132,135,138,141,144,147
123,126,129,132,135,138,141,144,147
138,141,144,147
```

**[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/93RmG/)**